# Casting pointer-to base class into a pointer-to derived class

Tags: c++, casting

I have read a bit about casting in C++. Coming from a C background, using normal `(type)` casting is common for things like `void *` but for C++, there are `dynamic_cast`, `reinterpret_cast`, `static_cast`, etc.

The problem/issue/question is about which of the above casts should be used when a conversion between a base pointer and a derived pointer.

Our data storage stores a pointer to a base class (`B`). The functions allocate the derived pointers (`D`).

The code example is as follows:

```
class B
{ int _some_data; }
class D : public B
{ int _some_more_data; }
```

The code then looks something like:

```
D *obj = new D;
obj->_some_data = 1;
obj->_some_more_data = 2;
<store obj>
```

Then later when we access the data:

```
B *objB = <get out data>
if (objB->_some_data == 1)
{ D *objD = (D *) objB; <do some processing> }
```

Now the cast I am concerned about is `D *objD = (D *) objB`.

Which cast should we be using?

Thanks.

Comment: In this case, dynamic_cast. It will check that the object really can be converted to a D* at runtime.

Comment: @BoBTFish `dynamic_cast` only works on polymorphic types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For related types that you know about but the compiler don't, use a `static_cast`.

But in your case you should not cast at all.

You write that

> Our data storage stores a pointer to a base class (B). The functions allocate the derived pointers (D).

That is to *throw away information*, which is not a good idea. Someone realized that it's not a good idea, that in fact it could not work, and therefore tried to keep that type information dynamically in the value of `B::_some_data`. The total effect: to throw away *the C++ support* for handling that type information, and substituting a very fragile and dirty homegrown solution.

In order to leverage the C++ support, make B a polymorphic class, i.e. with at least one `virtual` member:

```
struct B { virtual ~B() {} };
```

I removed the data member `_some_data` since apparently its only purpose was to keep track of the dynamic type, and now the C++ support does that, in practice via a so called "vtable pointer" in the object. The total object size is probably the same. The bug attraction and sheer ugliness is, however, reduced by some orders of magnitude. ;-)

Then,

```
struct D
    : B
{
    int some_more_data_;
    D( int v ): some_more_data_( v ) {}
};
```

And then, with polymorphic classes, your processing code can use a safe **`dynamic_cast`**, as follows:

```
B* const objB = getOutData();
if( D* const objD = dynamic_cast<D*>( objB ) )
{
    // do some processing using objD
}
```

Now this manual dynamic type checking is still very dirty and reflects a non-OO system architecture. With object oriententation, instead of operations checking what kind of data they have been given, the data effectively contains pointers to appropriate specialized operations. But I think it might be best to take one step at a time, and as a first step the above: getting rid of the fragile bug-attracting homegrown dynamic type checking scheme, and using relatively clean super-duper fresh nice-smelling good looking etc. C++ support for that. :-)

Comment: Thanks - _some_data is used all over to convey more information than just the above, but I get the point. However, I am not following `With object oriententation, instead of operations checking what kind of data they have been given, the data effectively contains pointers to appropriate specialized operations`. Does this mean that the base class contains virtual functions to all possible operations? Thanks.

Comment: No, it doesn't need to "contain virtual functions to all possible operations". An apparent such need is a design smell, but still, what is a practical solution when such apparent need pops up? Well, that's a *very* common question, it should IMHO be a FAQ, and the answer is the "visitor pattern". Too much to explain here, but essentially, you send in a visitor to the code that knows the type. And that code can then call back on the part of the visitor designed to handle the given type.

Comment: Thanks - I will look up the pattern - never heard of it.

Comment: "Does this mean that the base class contains virtual functions to all possible operations?" - not necessarily all possible operations, but ideally the base class has a big enough interface to allow you to implement all possible operations without needing to know/care which derived class you have. As Alf says, you might need visitor pattern (with double-dispatch), but whatever the details you'll try to design an interface for the base class that lets users build the operations they need from the functions available.

Comment: After some analysis of the design, it appears that we where not correctly using oop. We where changing class member variables outside which was really really bad. After some re-factoring, the actual need to cast like this falls away as we are using the classes correctly now. Thanks for the input to all.

Answer (score 7):

In this case, no cast is truly safe.

The safest would be `dynamic_cast`, but your objects aren't polymorphic so it doesn't apply here. But you should consider at least having a `virtual` destructor, as I can see you plan on extending the classes.

`static_cast` is not safe, as pointed out by this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c36yw7x9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) page:

```
class B {};

class D : public B {};

void f(B* pb, D* pd) {
   D* pd2 = static_cast<D*>(pb);   // not safe, pb may
                                   // point to just B

   B* pb2 = static_cast<B*>(pd);   // safe conversion
}
```

`reinterpret_cast` also has no checks, so don't rely on it.

Also, **casting to a pointer of a derived class is at least a code smell, if you need to do this it's 99% sure you have a flawed design.**

Comment: Why do you say his objects aren't polymorphic? They derive from each other... I'll agree on the missing `virtual destructor` tho.

Comment: `static_cast` would be legal, and do what he wants (but I agree with your analysis that the only good solution would be to make the objects polymorphic and use `dynamic_cast`).

Comment: @RedX In C++, an object type is only considered polymorphic if there is at least one virtual function.  Inheritance is an implementation technique which can be used for different purposes, not just polymorphism.  (I don't think anyone would consider an iterator polymorphic just because it derived from `std::iterator`.)

Comment: Thanks. We normally have the virtual destructors so the classes will be polymorphic. On the flawed design, we using a tree storage which provides a `void *` data storage param. There are some 60+ different permutations of data that all have 4 data items in common (some have more, so there is an inheritance tree...). How would you suggest storing these then other than the above? Thanks.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` not only has no checks, it's actually wrong in cases with multiple inheritance, where the address of the base class sub-object needn't be the same as the address of the complete object.

Comment: After some analysis of the design, it appears that we where not correctly using oop. After changing the classes to do things correctly no casting is required. Like you said, we were part of the 99% :) Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should use `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf `dynamic_cast` doesn't work since his classes aren't polymorphic.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf; Sergey he's actually doing nobody any favors by upvoting a wrong answer.

Comment: @Luchian: your argument that it's impossible to walk through the door because it's not open, ignores that fact that it's possible to open the door, and that that's what normal people do.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf actually it's not recommended to have virtual methods if you don't have to. It gives overhead.

Comment: @Luchian: in case you don't get it (I fear that you don't), when I ask someone for the Tørrfisk's office, and they tell me it's through that door over there, I do not presume that they intend that I should knock my way through the door's wood. Instead *I* presume that they mean I should open the door before going through it. That's the natural interpretation. Any other interpretation is dumb.

Comment: @Luchian: and again, your argument about "overhead", you don't know if there is any performance problem before you have **MEASURED**. you don't know the relative speeds of compiler-optimized RTTI versus hand-crafted manual dynamic type checking, before you have **MEASURED**. So you are advocating premature optimization and premature assumptions of inefficiency. What you do know without measuring, is that the manual checking is fragile and bug-ridden. Think about: it does not matter how fast your code is, if it is not correct (it can be made arbitrarily fast if it can be incorrect).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf it's not about how fast it is, but how much space it occupies in memory. The first virtual function introduced is guaranteed to increase the size of each object of the class by at least sizeof(void*) bytes.

Comment: @Luchian: consider the size of the manual type id, that disappears.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf you'd look pretty dumb though if you attempted to go into Tørrfisk's office and the door was locked, although you assumed it wasn't, right? I, for one, would at least knock, it's more civil.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf the size of the class increases when it becomes polymorphic. Try it out.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: in your answer you wrote "you should consider at least having a virtual destructor". That **inconsistent** with your argumentation here. In the comment above you point out for the second time that making the class polymorphic increases its size, which is **inconsistent** with the fact that few if any readers are unaware of that. And that comment ignored my response to the first, that with the manual type id gone, the net increase is likely 0. So, I am concluding that there is no point in continuing to try to help you understand. I suspect that you do understand.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf of course I understand. In my answer, I provide a workaround. I'm saying "use dynamic_cast and make your classes polymorphic - because you are extending them, not because you want to use dynamic_cast". Using `dynamic_cast` is an effect, not a cause. This answer just says "use dynamic_cast", and doesn't say the classes should be polymorphic, ergo it is wrong.